# Does I10n.js's toLocaleString(opts) merge the options?

Tags: javascript, localization, l10n.js

I'm looking to use l10n.js for a project. Seems like [defining the localization](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/blob/master/demo/localizations.js) strings is fairly easy. l10n.js defines the toLocaleString method. Is the input of that call merged or overwritten? I'd like to have two separate inputs into the methods be served into one and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A [comment](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/blob/c8ba297e34c55029314872e7bacf0486fc2866cf/l10n.js#L86) in the source suggests that the store of translations is extended when `String.toLocaleSource` is called.  Looking further [reveals](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/blob/c8ba297e34c55029314872e7bacf0486fc2866cf/l10n.js#L116-L120) that existing strings are overwritten and new ones are added next to the existing ones.